# Simple ADC conversion

Tags: adc

I am new to this site and am not an electrical engineer so I apologize for the basic nature of my question. I am interested in using analog to digital conversion to accomplish a simple task. I have been reading on here and other sites how to do this and am learning a great deal regarding the science but I am hoping to avoid coding or circuit building. I need a solution that works out of the box and would appreciate any information on how to start or if someone can just point me in the right direction. Maybe I am searching for the wrong things? The details of my project are below.

I have 0-5 volt analog signal on a 1/4" connector (can convert this). I need to convert this to a digital signal that I can monitor real time and record on a PC (and eventually export to CSV or Excel format). I have 2-3 channels (depending on the use).

I am trying to keep this simple so I am hoping to purchase a ADC box that will connect to my PC using ethernet or other standard cable and acquire this signal using a software out of the box.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+analog+digital+converter

Comment: What you are doing is called "data acquisition" (a.k.a. DAQ), and there are many commercial products designed specifically for this, ranging from hobbyist to professional. You should be able to find something suitable quickly. You're going to need to have some idea of the sample rate and precision (number of bits per sample) that you require.

Answer (score 1):

While such a device exists, it is likely to be somewhat expensive, as this isn't a terribly popular item for hobbyists to buy. However, an arduino nano clone like [this one](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7BF2K19102&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Gadgets-_-9SIA7BF2K19102&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoY7VBRDtARIsAHWoO-Lr0ft96ixMu7ERtTvVelpcJjfmqM-ZPAtItL7awKsza2ji8Ro6jmwaAtz9EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) is less than $5, and will connect to your pc using usb.

You don't have to program it either, because there's a sketch in **File**->**Examples**->**03. Analog**->**AnalogInOutSerial** that will do almost exactly what you want. All you'll need to do is convert your audio jack output to bare wires and solder them to the arduino. Then when you upload the sketch above to the arduino, it'll begin printing out the analog reading to the PC.

Comment: Indeed, this might or might not work for the actual purpose, but without any given details it is as reasonable an approach as any.  And it may be that experimenting with a system that *lacks* needed capability may be part of the learning how to understand what capability is needed.  Likely issues encountered may be limits to resolution, the presence of noise, limited sampling speed, and also a fairly high degree of *jitter* or irregularity in the timing of the samples.